# Getting Navigation Bar Color For View is Not Working

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationbar

I have getting navigation bar color and set it to view as background color but it's not as same as the color in bar.
I don't know why it's doing so.
Your solutions are welcome and i hope you help me in that matter.

**CODE**

```
     self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor]
     UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
     view.backgroundColor=  self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor;
```

In my application design we have same theme that's why it's not getting the theme of navigation view background color
there is some difference.

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: Please provide us with the code or link to your app.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-[UINavigationBar barTintColor]` property instead of tintColor
PS. Be aware of translucency :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
how can i add translucency in uiview.

Comment: I think you need UIVisualEffectView